# Finding and replacing data in JSON via PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

```
[
  {
    "packID": 195,
    "destinationID": 41,
    "phase": "LOC0-LOCAL"
  },
  {
    "packID": 41,
    "destinationID": 26,
    "phase": "LOC7-FLY"
  },
  {
    "packID": 42,
    "destinationID": 10,
    "phase": "LOC5-FLY"
  }
]
```

I want to change the stage and destination of package number `(packID)` 41. To do this, I first delete part 41 and add a new package. However, this does not work properly because the number 41 can be in other parts. If it does, it deletes other parts. How can I do this?

```
$packageID = 41;

$trPackages = json_decode($jsonContent, true);
    foreach ($trPackages as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($packageID, $value)) {
            unset($value[$key]); 
            // Result: Deleted packID:41 and packID: 195 ..
            $trPackages[] = ['packID' => 41, 'destinationID' => 99, 'phase' => 'LOC99-FLY'];
        }
    }
$trPackages = json_encode($trPackages);
...
```

How can I change only the data in package 41?

Comment: `if ($packageID == $value['packID']) {`?

Comment: @u_mulder I tried, but this time there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
/* ... */
$trPackages = json_decode($json, true);
$packageID = 41;

foreach ($trPackages as $key => $value) {
    if ($value["packID"] == $packageID) {
        unset($trPackages[$key]); 
        // Result: Deleted packID:41 and packID: 195 ..
        $trPackages [] = ['packID' => 41, 'destinationID' => 99, 'phase' => 'LOC99-FLY'];
    }
}

/* ... */
```